# Union of functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $F=\{f(n)\ |\ f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N\}$

I want to prove that for any $f,g\in F$, there is always an $h\in F$ that is different from $f$ and $g$, and is larger than both of them.

I believe that the proof of "$\mathbb N$ is an infinite set so there will always be a larger function" but it just doesn't feel like a strong proof. The other thing I had in mind is to union functions.

Since functions are actually relations, is it valid to declare a union of $f$ and $g$, and simply say that there will always be a larger function $h?$

Comment: Can't you just let $h(n)=f(n)+g(n)$?

Comment: $f\cup g\not\in F$ except if $f=g$.

Comment: Ozilophile, what do you mean by "larger"? Do you mean that $h(n) > \max ( f(n), g(n) )$? Or, do you mean that as a subset of $\mathbf{N} \times \mathbf{N}$, the set $h$ should contain both $f$ and $g$ as subsets?

Comment: Saaqib - the former.
NotNotLogical - this might be a dumb question, but is f(n) + g(n) always larger than f(n) or g(n) individually?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach will not work. The union of two functions is not necessarily a function. It's just a set of ordered pairs. But you want $h$ to be a function, not just any relation.

But your confusion might stem form the use of the word "larger". It doesn't mean that $h$ includes both $f$ and $g$. Rather it means that $f(n),g(n)<h(n)$, for all $n$.

Armed with this knowledge, and with the knowledge that $\Bbb N$ is an infinite set with a linear order without a maximum, in which every finite set is bounded, you should find the right answer much easier now.